# aws with eclipse cannot find keypair

Tags: amazon-ec2

I just installed the aws eclipse toolkit. I am having problems with the aws toolkit key pairs. When I go to the eclipse->windows->preferences->awstoolkit->key pairs I find no icons or names of my keypairs.pem file. I first downloaded all of the eclipse aws software modules with no issue. I did not include the android module as instructed. I downloaded the credentials and keypairs files from my ec2 instance. I placed the credentials file in .aws directory. I then filled out the aws toolkit credentials window and included in the default profile details a copy/paste of my access key id and secret access key. I think eclipse is seeing it because I noticed that after I rebooted eclipse it created another credentials file with the id and secret key reformatted. I placed the my keypair.pem in the .ec2 directory. Like I said earlier, when I go to the preferences->key pairs window there is nothing in the name field and I cannot associate my private keys with my amazon ec2 key pairs. Any help would be welcome...Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out.

I am new to AWS and did not understand that I had to first set up an IAM user and group and enable the necessary policies.  I found [a pretty good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_5DtTnL0d8) that goes over user/group settings.

Once I set up the policies I noticed that eclipse had immediate access to the aws cloud resources.  When I clicked the eclipse windows->preferences->keypairs my aws keypairs were displayed.  I clicked on the one I set up for the account and everything worked fine.

Comment: What policies do you use with Eclipse?